# PHP and MySQL "Database connection"

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

many time i try to connect PHP forms with MySQL Database but every time i got one message connection is not available.

so my question is that if some one have a knowledge of good tutorial websites then please tell me as i can learn from their

Comment: While it wasnt me whos marked you down. You show no code.. its hard to help you when we have nothing to work from. Show some code, if necessary make a test bit of code (mask out username + password credentials)

Comment: I didn't down vote either but the answer is simple, SO is meant for solving actual programming problems while you encounter them.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do something like this:

`$user="username";`
`$password="password";`
`$con=mysql_connect('10.10.10.10',$user,$password);`
`$db_selected = mysql_select_db("database_name", $con) or die("DB connecting problem");`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$user="uname";
$pwd="pwd";

$con = mysql_connect("localhost",$user,$pwd);
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

// Create database
if (mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE my_db",$con))
 {
 echo "Database created";
 }
else
 {
  echo "Error creating database: " . mysql_error();
 }


 $selectdb = mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);
  if (!$selectdb)
  {
     die('Database Not selected.');
  }

 mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Katty, you could head to the official PHP function reference page for MySQL which is:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php

initially focus on mysql_connect(). There's also some community submitted content, which could come handy for testing.

Also if you could provide the code u are using and error thrown, that would help.